# Expand dataframe by unique combinations and calculate their means

Tags: r, combinations

I'm trying to append rows to an dataset with combinations of the existing classes. I then want to calculate the means of the unique class combinations. It is similar to a pairwise post-hoc test but I want to keep the other columns in my dataset.

**Example dataset:**

| Class | Value | Treatment |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 1 |
| B | 2 | 1 |
| c | 3 | 1 |

**Result I want to have:**

| Class | Mean | Treatment |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 1 |
| B | 2 | 1 |
| c | 3 | 1 |
| AB | 1.5 | 1 |
| AC | 2 | 1 |
| ABC | 3 | 1 |
| BC | 2.5 | 1 |

I've tried combn but it doesn't give me the datatable I want. I'm trying to get an output like in HSD.test but without loosing the rest of my dataset. Can I somehow use the expand.grid function? Thanks for your help

Comment: How many classes can you have?

Comment: @EvanFriedland at the end I want to combine up to six classes

Comment: And does treatment matter at all?

Comment: Yes, I only want to combine the classes when the treatment is the same. There are more treatments, in the example, I only displayed one. The code should be combining all classes when they have the same treatment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `combn` like so:

```r
do.call(c, lapply(seq_along(df$Class), \(m) combn(df$Class, m, FUN = \(x) paste(x, collapse = ""))))
#[1] "A"   "B"   "C"   "AB"  "AC"  "BC"  "ABC"

do.call(c, lapply(seq_along(df$Class), \(m) combn(df$Class, m, FUN = \(x) mean(df$Value[match(x, df$Class)])))
#[1] 1.0 2.0 3.0 1.5 2.0 2.5 2.0
```

In a `dplyr` framework:

```r
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  reframe(Mean = do.call(c, lapply(seq_along(Class), \(m) combn(Class, m, FUN = \(x) mean(Value[match(x, Class)])))), 
          Class = do.call(c, lapply(seq_along(Class), \(m) combn(Class, m, FUN = \(x) paste(x, collapse = "")))), 
          Treatment = 1) %>% 
  select(Class, Mean, Treatment)

#   Class Mean Treatment
# 1     A  1.0         1
# 2     B  2.0         1
# 3     C  3.0         1
# 4    AB  1.5         1
# 5    AC  2.0         1
# 6    BC  2.5         1
# 7   ABC  2.0         1
```

Comment: wow Ive never seen the \(m) or \(x) syntax - what is that/where can I read more?

Comment: this is a shortcut for `function`.  this is from R 4.1.0. Some info here https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-announce/2021/000670.html

Comment: that is very helpful, thank you! :) I should have been a bit more specific; in my real data, there is more than one treatment. I only want to combine the classes, if they have the same treatment

Comment: Then you can do all that with `group_by(treatment)`

Answer (score 2):

This is a first step and the code is not generalizable:

```
librarfy(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)

library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

combos <- combn(unique(df$Class), 2, simplify = FALSE) # get all 2-combos
combos1 <- c(combos, list(unique(df$Class))) # add unique Class combo

result <- map_df(combos1, ~ data.frame(Class = paste0(.x, collapse = ""), stringsAsFactors = FALSE))


bind_rows(df, result) %>% 
  mutate(Value = case_when(
    Class == "AB" ~ (Value[Class=="A"]+ Value[Class=="B"])/2,
    Class == "AC" ~ (Value[Class=="A"]+ Value[Class=="C"])/2,
    Class == "BC" ~ (Value[Class=="B"]+ Value[Class=="C"])/2,
    Class == "ABC" ~ (Value[Class=="A"]+Value[Class=="B"]+ Value[Class=="C"])/2,
    TRUE ~ Value
  )) %>% 
  fill(Treatment, .direction = "down")
```

```
 Class Value Treatment
1     A   1.0         1
2     B   2.0         1
3     C   3.0         1
4    AB   1.5         1
5    AC   2.0         1
6    BC   2.5         1
7   ABC   3.0         1
```